# Installing sshfs on Docker with Debian Image - issues

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, fuse, sshfs

I have following problem.
Here is Dockerfile with Python app where I need to install sshfs to mount files from the sftp server via ssh.

```
# Set base image
FROM python:3.9

# Copy files
COPY id_rsa requirements.txt app.py /app/
COPY known_hosts /root/.ssh/
COPY ssh_config /etc/ssh

# Set working directory
WORKDIR app

# Install libraries
RUN    pip install -U pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && mkdir source \
    && chmod 600 id_rsa \
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get -y update

COPY fuse.conf /etc/

RUN dpkg --configure -a \
    && apt-get install -y sshfs \
    && sshfs user@ip_address:/C:/folder_name /app/source -o IdentityFile=/app/id_rsa,auto_cache,reconnect,transform_symlinks,follow_symlinks

# Run deamon
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

When I build Docker Image, it gives me the error

```
Configuration file '/etc/fuse.conf'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** fuse.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
 end of file on stdin at conffile prompt
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse
```

Here is how my fuse.conf looks like:

```
# The file /etc/fuse.conf allows for the following parameters:
#
# user_allow_other - Using the allow_other mount option works fine as root, in
# order to have it work as user you need user_allow_other in /etc/fuse.conf as
# well. (This option allows users to use the allow_other option.) You need
# allow_other if you want users other than the owner to access a mounted fuse.
# This option must appear on a line by itself. There is no value, just the
# presence of the option.

user_allow_other


# mount_max = n - this option sets the maximum number of mounts.
# Currently (2014) it must be typed exactly as shown
# (with a single space before and after the equals sign).

mount_max = 1000
```

I don't know whether the problem is that somehow DEFAULT=N is not taken when the image is built?
For the evidence, I can run docker in the interactive mode, I can install sshfs inside and mount it without problems (--privileged moded).

Comment: You'll get through this mechanical problem if you don't `COPY` the config file until after the package is installed.  You'll hit a bunch of other problems too, though: containers are usually prohibited from calling mount(2), and if you do succeed in mounting something in the Dockerfile, it won't be persisted in the image.  Can you mount the remote filesystem on the host and use the `docker run -v` option to attach it to the container, or use custom Docker named volume mount settings (in both cases without setting up anything in the Dockerfile)?

Comment: @DavidMaze: If I COPY fuse.conf after the packages is installed, then I get error: fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

Comment: You can't call modprobe(8) from inside Docker either (in general this is really really hard, since your Linux kernel modules are extremely version-specific but your image has no control over what kernel version the host runs).

Comment: @David Maze: can install sshfs and do sshfs being in the running docker container (interactive mode). But I can't build dockerf image having the same commands in the dockerfile.

Comment: In an image build you can't disable Docker's core security controls and you can't persist the mount.  This approach does not work.